# Is Kubernetes emptyDir different from no volume at all

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a Deployment that runs one container with a root user. It's perfectly clear that everything my application saves under `/data` will be ephemeral if I don't have any type of persistent volume and `volumeMounts` defined.

My question is what would be the purpose of specifying an [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) Volume and mounting it to `/data`? If I don't use [fancy features](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#emptydirvolumesource-v1-core) for emptyDir like `medium` or `sizeLimit` isn't it the same as using no volumes at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the main features of the emptyDir is that it can be mounted on multiple containers inside the same Pod.
If you don't use this feature I guess there is not much to gain from it. If I remember correctly emptyDirs are preserved when the container inside the pod are restarted but not when the pod is re-scheduled.

Comment: Do you know "where" is the data stored if no volume is mounted ? Does it uses the Node storage ?

Comment: It uses the node ephemeral storage or memory depending on the medium you chosen. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir